# Sort an array of software versions in descending order

Tags: php, sorting, version, string-comparison

How can I sort this array of version values?

```
$available_databases = array(
    "4.0.1",
    "trunk",
    "branch",
    "4.1.0",
    "4.0.3"
);
```

so that the result is

```
4.1.0
4.0.3
4.0.1
branch
trunk
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use PHP's built-in array operations and such to do a lot of the heavy lifting for you, thus cutting out a lot of the apparent complexity:

```
$names = preg_grep('/^\D/', $arr);
$versions = preg_grep('/^\d/', $arr);

usort($versions, 'version_compare');
usort($names, 'strcasecmp');

$sorted = array_merge(array_reverse($versions), $names);
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use the [usort](http://php.net/usort) function.

```
$isVersion = function($a) { return is_numeric( str_replace('.', '', $a) ); };
$sortFunction = function($a, $b) use($isVersion) { 
    if( $isVersion($a) && $isVersion($b) ) { 
        return version_compare($b, $a); // reversed for your proper ordering
    } elseif( $isVersion($a) ) { 
        return -1;
    } elseif( $isVersion($b) ) { 
        return 1;
    } else { 
        return strcasecmp($a, $b);
    }
};

usort($yourArray, $sortFunction);
```

The usort function lets you use your own custom comparison callback. I wrote one here for you with the logic you desired: if both comparable items are versions, it uses `version_compare` to compare them with the parameters reversed since you want descending order. If the second comparable item is a string and the first is a version, the version is said to be "lower" than the string, and vice-versa. If both items are strings, it uses the `strcasecmp` comparison function to determine the proper ordering.
Example in use: [codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/PRVaxr)

Comment: Just a note:  In the case where `$a` and/or `$b` are not version numbers, a lexical sort (like `strcasecmp`) will already put them in the right order (number first, then name).  Seems to me you could get rid of the middle two cases.

Comment: Looks like this only works on >= PHP 5.3.0, 5.2.* throws an error.

Comment: @Shaquin: Yeah...closures were introduced in 5.3.  If you're still using 5.2, you need to update anyway.  :)  But you can accomplish a similar result using `create_function` and/or regular old named functions.

Comment: What I mean is most online PHP interpreters that measure time and memory run PHP 5.2. I've edited my post to include a speed/memory comparison.

Comment: @Shaquin: And most *servers*, where you actually *care* about time and memory usage, run 5.3.  :)  The online interpreters still running 5.2 need to update.

Comment: When I copy your code into eclipse I got `function`s highlighted as it is an syntax error. I can see that it works in codepad but any idea how I can make it work?

Comment: @Radek: If Eclipse doesn't realize this is valid PHP code, then it either needs an update or sucks even worse than i remember.  PHP 5.3 has been out for over 3 years.  That's, like, forever in internet years.

Comment: @cHao: I got an error even when I run the code :-( using 5.3.x

Comment: @Radek: This version should run fine.  The version that Shaquin made for 5.2, though, has `$sortFunction` rather than `'sortFunction'` in the line that actually does the sort.  That won't work once you're not assigning a function to `$sortFunction`.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with some [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) and a couple of loops.

**Example:**

```
<?php
$arr = array("4.0.1", "trunk", "branch", "4.1.0", "4.0.3", "1.2", "1.31", "1.10", "1.4.5");
natsort($arr);
$count = count($arr);
$alpha = array();
$new_arr = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    if(!is_numeric(str_replace('.', '', $arr[$i]))) {
        $alpha[] = $arr[$i];
    } else {
        $new_arr[] = $arr[$i];
    }
    $arr[$i] = null;
}
rsort($new_arr);
sort($alpha);
$new_arr = array_merge($new_arr, $alpha);
var_dump($new_arr);
?>
```

**[Demo here.](http://ideone.com/XdXNx)**

Comment: Believe he wants the numeric part descending and the alpha part ascending, otherwise cool demo.

Comment: @shaunhusain It does sort the array in the order that he wants, though..?

Comment: No notice he wants 4.1.0 to appear first not last in the numeric list, I believe the basic issue is that he wants a mix of an ascending and a descending sort with regard to the ASCII characters, basically the only thing I can think of is to split the array into two arrays sort each separately then re-combine, but I'm unfamiliar with the solution provided below.  Your answer I believe suffers from the same issue as the natcasesort solution.  After reading through the usort solution it seems correct.

Comment: @shaunhusain Nah, usort's there specifically for cases where the built in sort functions won't handle it. My solution works fine and just follows the logic he laid out (: Splitting it into two arrays would also work, but for larger arrays wouldn't be particularly efficient.

Comment: @Lusitanian Yah I was just saying I thought your solution was correct gave you an up-vote too, basically from your explanation usort basically acts like a compareTo in Java to allow you to customize how sorts end up sorting items in a list.  I think what you proposed is probably best, I just wasn't aware of the php function (only dabble in PHP and it's been a while, thanks for the info).

Comment: Yah so I think either this solution or @Lusitanian's solution will work, I believe Lussitanian's solution would ultimately be more efficient in terms of both memory and CPU

Comment: huh interesting I wonder why using a compare function wouldn't end up being faster unless it has to do with the number of conditions being checked (memory usage is understandable if pointers are simply being moved around rather than values being copied).  If I was the OP or could +1 you again I would

Comment: @Shaquin: The speed difference seems due to the use of `print_r` rather than `var_dump`.  See [my ideone edit with only that changed](http://ideone.com/9p51N) (and the function name fixed).

Comment: @Shaquin: A millisecond measurement would be meaningless at this scale, really.  If performance is really important, a meaningful test would include a larger data set and/or more reps.

Comment: @cHao True, true. Anyway, I've updated my question, I'll edit it again to say they take the same amount of time.

Comment: @Shaquin: Might be because you're not sorting versions quite right.  Without `version_compare` or `natsort` or something like that, `1.10` comes before (or since it's reversed, after) `1.9`

Answer (score 0):

You merely need to invert the `version_compare()` evaluation.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IWKp6))

```
$array = ["4.0.1", "trunk", "branch", "4.1.0", "4.0.3"];

usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return version_compare($b, $a);
});

var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '4.1.0',
  1 => '4.0.3',
  2 => '4.0.1',
  3 => 'branch',
  4 => 'trunk',
)
```

From PHP7.4, arrow function syntax can be used. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Qsksd))

```
usort($array, fn($a, $b) => version_compare($b, $a));
```